# dnsmasq DHCP server is not selecting IPs inside of the specified range after being offered the right ones

Tags: ip, dhcp, dnsmasq

I have my DHCP server which I specifically set the ip range to be between: 10.53.70.100 -- 10.53.70.200 but there are sometimes I get IPs outside from this range. For example, the last server I created got the IP 10.53.70.245, so I just wanted to know why my ip range setting is not working.

**Just to note I'm using dnsmasq instead of dhcpd service for this.**

Here’s the log from the DHCP server:

```
Mar 20 10:32:46 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 available DHCP range: 10.53.70.100 -- 10.53.70.200
Mar 20 10:32:46 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 client provides name: dnstest
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 DHCPDISCOVER(ens192) 10.53.70.245 00:50:56:8f:d4:6f
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 tags: ens192
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 DHCPOFFER(ens192) 10.53.70.177 00:50:56:8f:d4:6f
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 requested options: 1:netmask, 28:broadcast, 2:time-offset, 121:classless-static-route,
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 requested options: 15:domain-name, 6:dns-server, 12:hostname,
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 requested options: 40:nis-domain, 41:nis-server, 42:ntp-server,
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 requested options: 26:mtu, 119:domain-search, 3:router, 121:classless-static-route,
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 requested options: 249, 33:static-route, 252, 42:ntp-server
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 next server: 10.53.70.5
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 sent size:  1 option: 53 message-type  2
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 sent size:  4 option: 54 server-identifier  10.53.70.5
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 sent size:  4 option: 51 lease-time  12h
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 sent size:  4 option: 58 T1  6h
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 sent size:  4 option: 59 T2  10h30m
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 sent size:  4 option:  1 netmask  255.255.255.0
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 sent size:  4 option: 28 broadcast  10.53.70.255
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 sent size:  4 option:  6 dns-server  10.53.70.5
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 sent size:  9 option: 15 domain-name  example.io
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 sent size:  4 option:  3 router  10.53.70.1
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 available DHCP range: 10.53.70.100 -- 10.53.70.200
Mar 20 10:32:49 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 1927259932 client provides name: dnstest
Mar 20 10:32:52 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 2099714365 available DHCP range: 10.53.70.100 -- 10.53.70.200
Mar 20 10:32:52 dhcp dnsmasq-dhcp[7657]: 2099714365 client provides name: dnstest
```

As you can see there's the line where it says:

```
DHCPOFFER(ens192) 10.53.70.177 00:50:56:8f:d4:6f
```

Which it will be a correct Ip since it's inside of the range. However I see the line where it says:

```
DHCPDISCOVER(ens192) 10.53.70.245 00:50:56:8f:d4:6f
```

So, at the end the server takes this IP ending in .245, so my question is why it takes an IP that's outside of the allowed range?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your DHCP server set as being "authoritative" ?

Comment: is there such a setting in dnsmasq?

Comment: `grep -r authoritative . | grep dhcp` under the source dir for dnsmasq turns up a bunch of hits

Comment: @thrig That line is commented out, but in the comment before it says I shouldn't uncomment that line unless I know what I'm doing otherwise I can mess up with my network, and that makes me nervous :/

Comment: The client requests (DHCPDISCOVER) the .245 address and the server responds  (DHCPOFFER) with .177 which is within it's permitted range.
Maybe this is a case of the client ignoring the server's response and keeping it's old IP address?

Comment: @garethTheRed so how can I make that the client doesn't ignore the DHCPOFFER request?

Comment: Exactly which client? You don't mention what your client is :-)

Comment: I meant DHCP client.